# Why is $\left( \begin{smallmatrix} x & y \\ y & t \\ \end{smallmatrix} \right)$ orthogonally similar to this?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

When working on a problem, I encountered the following statement.

> Let $x,y,t \in \mathbb R$
>
> $\left( \begin{smallmatrix}  x & y \\  y & t \\ \end{smallmatrix} \right)$ is orthogonally similar to $\left( \begin{smallmatrix}  a & b \\  -b & a \\ \end{smallmatrix} \right)$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb R$

In order to prove it, I considered multiplying by conjugate rotation matrices with unknown angle $h$

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 \cos (h) & \sin (h) \\
 -\sin (h) & \cos (h) \\
\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
 x & y \\
 y & t \\
\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
 \cos (h) & -\sin (h) \\
 \sin (h) & \cos (h) \\
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
\scriptstyle{ \sin (h) (y \cos (h)+t \sin (h))+\cos (h) (x \cos (h)+y \sin (h))} & \scriptstyle{\cos (h) (y \cos (h)+t \sin (h))-\sin (h) (x \cos (h)+y \sin (h))} \\
 \scriptstyle{\cos (h) (y \cos (h)-x \sin (h))+\sin (h) (t \cos (h)-y \sin (h))} & \scriptstyle{\cos (h) (t \cos (h)-y \sin (h))-\sin (h) (y \cos (h)-x \sin (h))}
\end{pmatrix}$$
But finding a suitable $h$ is actually not trivial ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false. Take $x=t=0$, $y\ne0$. The eigenvalues of the first matrix are real $(\pm y)$. The eigenvalues of the second matrix are $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=a$ if $b=0$ and they are not real if $b\ne0$. Thus, these two matrices cannot be similar, because similar matrices have the same eigenvalues.